# Ubuntu detect wrong monitor

Tags: multiple-monitors, display-driver, ubuntu-17.04

I'm in trouble with my PC. I have only one monitor, but Ubuntu detects two.

[image]

The monitor that was real on my system is Dell Inc. 24". When I start my computer, I can't see the login screen (because it is displayed on "Built-in display"), and I have to do like this: Enter -> Type password -> Enter to login my account. If I use more than one account then I can't see those on login screen.

I'm using Ubuntu 17.04, Intel i5 7500, Intel 630HD, 8GB-RAM. Windows does not have  same problem.

Answer (score 1):

Seems to be a bug in with the Intel HD driver. The false monitor needs to be disregarded on boot.

Use xrandr to find the false display.

```
xrandr -q
```

Then match that to the drm display options

```
ls /sys/class/drm
```

My non existent extra screen was DSI1 in xrandr but card0-DSI-1 in /sys/class/drm)

Edit the grub configuration file to disable the screen before booting the os.

```
sudo gedit /etc/default/grub
```

Change:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
```

To

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="video=DSI-1:d"
```

Replace DSI-1 with whatever the display was named in /e
/sys/class/drm minus card0

then run

```
sudo update-grub
```

and reboot.